# Import path for decorator-wrapped function?

Tags: python, decorator

Assuming I have a decorator and a wrapped function like this:

```
def squared(method):
    def wrapper(x, y):
        return method(x*x, y*y)
    return wrapper

@squared
def sum(x, y):
    return x+y
```

I have other code that would like to call the undecorated version of the `sum` function.  Is there an import trick that can get me to this unwrapped method?  If my code says `from some.module.path import sum` then, I get the wrapped version of the `sum` method, which is not what I want in this case.  (Yes, I know I could break this out into a helper method, but that breaks some of the cleanliness of the pattern I'm going for here.)

I'm okay with adding extra "magic" to the decorator to provide some alternate symbol name (like `orig_sum`) that I could then import, I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def unwrap(fn):
    return fn.__wrapped__

def squared(method):
    def wrapper(x, y):
        return method(x*x, y*y)
    wrapper.__wrapped__ = method
    return wrapper

@squared
def sum(x, y):
    return x+y

sum(2,3)       ->  13
unwrap(sum)(2,3)  ->  5
```

Comment: From another source file, is it possible to `from foo.squared.wrapper import orig as sum`?

Comment: @slacy, I have to say that IMO, what you're suggesting is far less "clean" than Reiner Gerecke's decorator-less version.

Comment: BTW, even better would be `setattr(wrapped, method.__name__, method)` :)

Comment: @slacy: in general, to the best of my knowledge, no - the original function is buried in compiled byte-code.

Comment: I really like your use of the unwrap helper.  In fact, one could make that a decorator...

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
def squared(method):
    def wrapper(x, y):
        return method(x*x, y*y)
    return wrapper

def sum(x, y):
    return x+y

squared_sum = squared(sum)
```

It's still a decorator, but you still can import `squared` and `sum` without any magic. Not sure if that's what you meant by 'helper method', but I find this much cleaner than a `sum` method, which actually sums the squares of its inputs.

Comment: Yes, that would of course work, but it doesn't have the cleanliness of the Python decorator syntax. :)  As you likely have guessed, I'm actually not summing and squaring in my code, this is just a synthetic example that illustrates the behavior I want.  But, your point is valid, and maybe I shouldn't use the @decorator syntax.

Comment: late to the party, but you could:
    @squared
    def squared_sum(x, y):
        return sum(x,y)